# Why did that person die?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, bloodline

In the second season of the *[Bloodline](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3520702/)* series we are introduced to a small-time crook Ozzy, who wants to earn some easy money from the Rayburn family: when John Rayburn starts his Sheriff campaign, Ozzy decides to approach them saying that "he knows things that could harm his campaign". He gets paid, but of course, that is not enough.

> Unknowingly to Ozzy, Rayburns have a connection with a shady businessman Roy, who is actively supporting John's campaign. Roy decides that Ozzy is a liability and orders a hit on Ozzy. Lucky bastard manages to kill the hitman... but then Ozzy comes back and tries to reach directly to Roy. They arrange a meeting in a public place, but instead of Roy, two muscular guys show up and invite Ozzy for a drive. But this time, Ozzy is prepared - he pulls a gun on the would-be kidnappers and... shots himself in the head.

Why the hell did he do that? He is the "I'm smarter than everyone" type of a guy and this time, he actually might be right. He could run away, cry for help or simply shoot the (apparently unarmed) guys. Does his earlier visit in the church (and looking for an apparently non-existing priest) have anything to do with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[John Leguizamo explains](https://www.cinemablend.com/television/1664709/why-bloodline-made-such-a-shocking-move-with-ozzy-according-to-john-leguizamo):

> **Some of the shocks came specifically because of Netflix's unexpected cancellation announcement**, which was a detriment to the storytelling that the three creators had planned. One particular character who suffered the woes of story-minimizing was **John Leguizamo**'s intimidating **Ozzy Delveccio**, who met a most gruesome fate late in the season. Here's what Leguizamo thought about that scene, and how he helped inform it.
>
> > Todd and I really talked about it. He told me I was going to come to an end and I said, 'I understand that.' You still mourn for your character; you created it. But **I said, 'I don't want anybody to take my life. If somebody's going to take my life, I'm going to take my own life.'** And so Todd and I talked about that, and **I just felt that Ozzy would never let anyone take his life from him.** If he felt like he was coming to an end, he would do it before they did. That's the kind of pride that he had.
> >
> > So then [Todd] reverse engineered that and started setting up this character so that once I got kicked in the head, which happened to someone in my family --- I don't want to get into it because it's kind of personal --- but they got bullied and beat up so badly that they had brain damage and they changed. I said I think that's what happened, because it was the same kind of beating up with boots and stuff, so **they created this [storyline where] --- I got hit in the head and I changed. Ozzy changed.**

The "Todd" he refers to is one of *Bloodline*'s creators: **Todd A. Kessler**, **Glenn Kessler** and **Daniel Zelman**.